# How can you "cut" a contour out of an image with OpenCv?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, computer-vision

I have Image A, image B and mask M, all with the same dimensions.

I want to super impose image B over image A. Some regions in image A are to be kept identical however. These regions have already been identified inside of the mask, so all that is needed is to set all corresponding pixels inside in image B that are inside of the mask contours to transparent.

In other words, by using `findContours` in the mask, I know the outlines of the regions that need to be erased from image B, but I don't know the interior points.

Does anyone know if it is possible to do the above?

EDIT:
Using cv:FILLED and drawContours to fill those regions with a single color then copying only the pixels with those colors worked.

Comment: Can you provide samples of A, B, M and expected result?

Comment: `B.copyTo(A, M);`

Comment: You can feel free to answer your own question with the solution that worked for you; otherwise if you found a duplicate that answered your question feel free to link it and we can mark it as a dupe. Also note Miki's solution right here ^, which is the idiomatic/explicit way to do it (reads as copy values of B into A at the non-zero mask locations)

Comment: So your solution is to convert the mask to a contour, then draw the contour filling it in, which gets you back to the mask... I don't understand that. In any case, you should post your answer as an answer, rather than answering inside the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043621/create-a-mask-and-delete-inside-contour-in-opencv-python). With this function you can obtain the result image assuming you have a binary mask:

```
def cmb(foreground,background,mask):
    result = np.zeros_like(foreground)
    result[mask] = foreground[mask]
    inv_mask = np.logical_not(mask)
    result[inv_mask] = background[inv_mask]
    return result
```

Comment: could you please provide the equivalent code in C++?

Comment: FYI, you can use `~a` to invert a logical array `a`, but more importantly there's no use initializing it to zeros since it gets filled in both spots. You could simply do `result = background.copy()` followed by `result[mask] = foreground[mask]` and be done. Anyways, it's not particularly bad form to link a solution and copy the solution (in fact it's good form to provide the solution when linking), but if the question is the same, it should be simply voted to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Python != C++. Translating this answer to C++ is not trivial.